# Android Studio 2.1 Emulator Blank Screen Issue

Tags: android, emulation

I upgraded my Android Studio to the latest version, but each time i run the emulator, all i get is "draw: no program". Emulator runs, but nothing is visible on the emulator. Please check the image attached. I have no idea what could be wrong here.[Click here to see image please.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLwGz.png)

Comment: Use genymotion ...fast and convenient

Comment: Could you try running the emulator from command line with a -verbose switch? that would print lots of debugging data out, some of it might actually show the issue. "no program" usually means that some OpenGL operation failed during initialization, and I'd like to know which one - to be able to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I don't have many "happy endings" with AVD. So I can't solve your specific problem

I suggest you to try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). It's an emulator too, but it use Virtualbox with a "image" of android, works fast and have more resources.

As well, if you can,it's good to use physical devices too

Sometimes virtualbox doesn't work well, so you can youse [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/pt-br/index.html?), it's another emulator, It's not property for debug, but you still can run your app.

Comment: I have both bluestacks and Genymotion installed, but my genymotion also displays exactly like my andoroid emulator.  I have contacted their support but got no response either. Kinda stuck with all this emulator problem really.

Comment: This is so strange, your pc drivers are updated? vga drivers ok?

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter a glitch of this sort, sometimes all you can do is delete virtual device and recreate it. Especially after updating because you don't know exactly what's the cause of the problem.

Comment: Deleted and re-created...still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with the GPU emulation. In this case setting GPU emulation in AVD options to Software might help (Emulation Performance - Graphics)
It won't be fast, but at least you would see some output.